# cannot reach symfony app on my debian 404 Not Found

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony, debian

looking for solutions for a small challenge

i have my local network (router)
i have debian server on first machine where i have installed a symfony in /var/www/my-symf-app
i changed /etc/site-available
and
/etc/hosts
for my new web site
when i'm trying to reach in a web browser my-symf-app from my debian machine 
--> and it works fine

but when I'm using targeting my server from another PC with my ip http://192.168.0.47/coach.dev
i have a situation
and i receive a 404 not found

but when I'm targeting my debian server just with http://192.168.0.47
it works fine, it shows me a index.htm Works find

i have commented code in config.php
for if server something throw error forbidden

could you pls explain me what I'm doing wrong and how can i fix it?

my /etc//sites-available/coach

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName coach.dev
    ServerAlias www.coach.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/coach/web

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/coach/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
```

my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       coach.dev
```

Comment: The Apache rewrite module is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on the 2nd computer ip and domainname to hosts.
I mean add ip adress of the server and his domain to host on second computer it should work.